# Unable to connect unless already logged in

Tags: xorg, vnc

I wanted to connect to Ubuntu 18.04 remotely using VNC. This is currently working only if I am already logged in locally.

The Ubuntu machine is a VM and is running xorg.

Not sure how to get things going without having to do a local log in first.

Help very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

try using "screen"

the usage is simple-

```
screen <the command you use to start vnc sever>
```

Comment: How do you mean use the screen command ? Where would I need to run this ? I am trying to log in to the machine from a mac using VNC.

Comment: You would have to run it on your local machine. You have to start the vnc server on your local(The right term is remote actually, the machine you are trying to connect to) machine right. Also you will have to kill your previous instance of the vnc server before you use screen

Comment: How does that solve the problem to first login on the Ubuntu VM and starting the VNC server manually?

Comment: You obviously have to login at least once to start the server. You can't "remotely" start a vnc server  if that is what you are looking for. Screen preserves the login session of the vnc server.